# Validity on a study about spanking children

Tags: discipline

Earlier today, I got into an argument with someone about spanking children and whether or not it caused them to become more violent later in life in addition to other issues.
Eventually, this [article](http://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2013/12/131211103958.htm) surfaced and we debated its merits.

> A new book by Murray Straus, founder and co-director of the Family Research Lab and professor emeritus of sociology at the University of New Hampshire, brings together more than four decades of research that makes the definitive case against spanking, including how it slows cognitive development and increases antisocial and criminal behavior.

Is this a valid study?  If not, what are some more reliable studies?

Please do not link this to any of the previous questions.  I would like answers about this study in particular.

Comment: Hi, and welcome! This will be pretty hard to answer as it's worded; the article was about a **book** with over 100 studies. If you can reword this question to narrow the scope, it would help in getting useful answers.

Comment: From what I can tell from that press release, Dr. Straus essentially has done [a literature review](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literature_review), which is a way to summarize a lot of research into one central publication (and readers interested in more detail of specifics can then delve into the papers they want to). It's certainly "valid" in the sense that this is a fairly common type of publication, but I'm not really sure what you're looking for beyond that.

Comment: I don't think your question can be well answered the way it's written. It all depends on how many times it's done, how it is done, when, and also if it's not done than replaced by what (are you comparing it to negotiation, time-out, yelling, confiscation, ...).

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR** read the original paper and other literature and come to your own conclusion.

Generally speaking, you have to remember that correlation does not mean causality. It can be very difficult to tease out confounding factors in a properly controlled study, let alone social sciences papers where controls aren't really feasible.

Beyond that you shouldn't trust the article you linked to, go back to the original source which I think [is this presentation](http://pubpages.unh.edu/~mas2/CP125-Israel-2013.pdf). Two things really struck me reading through it.

- First was how inconsistent some of the data is. For example, slide 5 says 33% of Swedish children are spanked daily... but slide 8 says the number of "frequently spanked" children in Sweden is 17%. I'm not necessarily surprised (I take a rather dim view of the rigour of published research in general to begin with), but this does speak to the challenges this kind of research faces.
- Second was an absence of an attempt to find or acknowledge confounding factors. For example, whether or not factors associated with criminality like socio-economic status are also correlated with levels of spanking. This kind of analysis may be somewhere, but I haven't a hot clue where to find it.

All that being said, I can sit down and pick apart pretty much any paper out there, but my analysis will say as much about my world-view as anything else. Go to the guy's webpage (there is a link in the original article you cited) and read his papers with a critical eye. Then search the literature for papers on the benefits of spanking, and the negatives of alternatives to spanking, and come to your own conclusions.